# How to display source code from inlined sourcemap of JS file in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, source-maps

I have a library in form of JavaScript file with inlined sourcemap. I want to see the original TypeScript source code of that library in VSCode. Is there any extension for that? I expected something like right-clicking on library file and "show source", but did not found anything.